# Why are nanosleep() and usleep() too slow?

Tags: c, debian

I have a program that generates packets to send to a receiver.  I need an efficient method of introducing a small delay between the sending of each packet so as not to overrun the receiver.  I've tried usleep() and nanosleep() but they seem to be too slow.  I've implemented a busy wait loop and had more success, but it's not the most efficient method, I know.  I'm interested in anyone's experiences in trying to do what I'm doing.  Do others find usleep() and nanosleep() to function well for this type of application?

Thanks,

Danny Llewallyn

Comment: Question is very vague - how long a delay do you need and why do you think that nanosleep/usleep can not provide this delay ?

Comment: Obviously, we don't know the details of what you're doing, but I would think nanosleep would be sufficient.

How accurate do your sleeps need to be?  The OS will guarantee that at least the requested amount of time of delay will transpire - but it doesn't make similar guarantees about the amount of time beyond the sleep request that it will wake-up.

Comment: On my Raspberry Pi it takes more then 73us to just call nanosleep. I guess I have to go to busy-loops too.

Answer (score 9):

The behaviour of the sleep functions for very small intervals is heavily dependent on the kernel version and configuration.

If you have a "tickless" kernel (`CONFIG_NO_HZ`) and high resolution timers, then you can expect the sleeps to be quite close to what you ask for.

Otherwise, you'll generally end up sleeping at the granularity of the timer interrupt.  The timer interrupt interval is configurable (`CONFIG_HZ`) - 10ms, 4ms, 3.3ms and 1ms are the common choices.

Comment: This answer seems to be making assumptions about which OS the user is running.

Comment: It is Debian.  I should have been more clear.  I think this is the issue.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a bad design. Ideally the receiver would queue any extra data it receives , and then do its message processing separate thread. In that way, it can handle bursts of data without relying on the sender to throttle its requests.

But perhaps such an approach is not practical if (for example) you do not have control of the receiver's code, or if this is an embedded application.

Comment: You are making the assumption that the receiver is a bit of software on a computer somewhere.  What if it some hardware device with only a limited amount of buffer for incoming packets?

Comment: Absolutely - I was hoping the OP could clarify this in his question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the higher level approaches other commenters have mentioned are not available to you, then a common approach in embedded/microcontroller land is to create a NOP-loop of the required length.

A [NOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) operation takes one CPU cycle and in an embedded environment you typically know exactly what clock speed your processor is running at so you can just use a simple for-loop conatining `_NOP()` or if only a very short delay is required then don't bother with a loop, just add in the required number of nops.

```
regTX = 0xFF;  // Transmit FF on special register

// Wait three clock cycles
_NOP();
_NOP();
_NOP();

regTX = 0x00; // Transmit 00
```

Answer (score 0):

I can speak for Solaris here, in that it uses an OS timer to wake up sleep calls. By default the minimum wait time will be 10ms, regardless of what you specify in your `usleep`. However, you can use the parameters `hires_tick = 1` (1ms wakeups) and `hires_hz =` in the `/etc/system` configuration file to increase the frequency of timer wake up calls.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing things at the packet level, where you need to worry about such things as overrunning the reciever. Why not use a TCP stream to transmit the data? Let TCP handle things like flow rate control and packet retransmission.

If you've already got a lot invested in the packetized approach, you can always use a layer on top of TCP to extract the original packets of data from the TCP stream and feed these into your existing functions.